# Nuxt ssr with firebase hosting and functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I created my app with nuxt, and I want to deploy by Firebase hosting.

So I edit my **firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "testssr.js",
      "node_modules/**",
      "/plugins/**",
      ...
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/**",
        "function": "render"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And create a function **render**

```
let app = express();
let config = {
  dev: false
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
app.use(nuxt.render)

exports.render = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

But, it doesn't work and I can't find any error.

When I create an express app, it works.

```
const config = {
  dev: false
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

app.use(nuxt.render)

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('works')
})
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to terminate a http function with one of the following:

```
response.send()
response.redirect()
response.end()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions